# Where can I find my Chrome extension's public key?

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, public-key

I'm updating my Chrome extension to use Firebase for authorization and database support and [this page](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/quickstart-js/auth/chromextension/readme/) tells me I need the extension's item ID, which I have, and its public key, which I don't. I recall that the public key used to be visible in the developer dashboard, but I don't see it anymore. Where can I find it and why did Google remove it?

Comment: You can copy it from manifest.json of this extension installed from the web store. It's in the browser profile directory.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't understand what you're saying. What's the "browser profile directory"? Also, it's not in manifest.json. All that's there is what I put into it.

Comment: If you google up "browser profile directory" you can find a tutorial. Inside this directory you will see `Extensions`, there you'll find your extension as served by the web store so its manifest.json will have `key`.

Comment: @wOxxOm How can I close my question and give you the credit?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64004553/).

Comment: @wOxxOm I didn't see anything at the link that would help.

Comment: The answer I've linked says "Key is available in the new UI --> Package on left side menu --> Public Key"

Comment: @wOxxOm I see that, but the answer wasn't provided by you and in any case, I'm unable to to give that person credit,although I did give him an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

@wOxxOm answered the question as follows:

If you google up "browser profile directory" you can find a tutorial. Inside this directory you will see Extensions, there you'll find your extension as served by the web store so its manifest.json will have key.